# How to Display only certain rows in gridview based on which user(session) have login

Tags: c#, session, gridview, webforms

I have two tables called appointment and patient with relationship with each other using patientID. What I want to achieve is user/patient who login will only get to see their own appointment instead of all appointment/allRows in the gridview. Etc, at the first attached image, since I am login as adam, I only want to view the row with appointmentID 2 only since in the appointment table in attached image 2, patientID number 3 belongs to Adam in the patient table. By the way I did stored the patient ID in a session after logging in. The codes for login and appointment page are below. Any help?

**View Appointment Page**
[image: View Appointment Page]

**Patient and Appointment Tables**
[image: Patient and Appointment Tables]

**//LOGIN FORM CODES**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
        string pwd = txtPassword.Text;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            // Another method --> cmd.CommandText = "SELECT patientID, pUsername, pPassword FROM patient WHERE pUsername='" + user + "' AND pPassword='" + pwd + "'  ";
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT patientID, pUsername, pPassword FROM patient WHERE pUsername= @user and pPassword= @password;";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16).Value = user;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = pwd;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);

            int id = (cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null) ? Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) : 0;
            if (id > 0)
            {
                Session.Add("ID", id);
                Session.Add("Username", txtUserName.Text);
                Session.Add("Password", txtPassword.Text);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, true);
                Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid Username or Password";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**//APPOINTMENT FORM CODES**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class member_viewappointment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // call BindGridView
            bindGridView();

        }
    }

    private void bindGridView()
    {
        //get connection string from web.config
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText = "SELECT * from appointment";
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

            myConnect.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            grdViewAppointment.DataSource = dt;
            grdViewAppointment.DataBind();
            lblResult.Text = "";

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnect.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `patientID` to the query in `bindGridVIew`

```
int id= (int)Session["ID"];
```

with

```
string strCommandText = "SELECT * from appointment WHERE patientID = " + id.ToString();
```

Code is not tested but that should give you what you want.

Comment: I think your line of session should be this int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString()); cause if i use your line of session code i get Error The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context. @Peter Smith

Comment: Hi, I _had_ mistyped the brackets `()` instead of `[]`. But glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First check if logged in user is not NULL then add a filter (WHERE clause) to "SELECT * from appointment" so your query will look like

```
SELECT * from appointment Where yourcolumn = logged-in user
```